# How to use progressbar, backgroundworker, windows form together in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, backgroundworker

I am stuck on an issue where I am using Backgroundworker to show the progress of my work in a progress bar. Code used for backgroundworker:-

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
           Delegate del= new DELEGATE(simulateHeavyWork);
           this.Invoke(del);

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        percentLabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        }
    }
```

I have created a delegate on the code:-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private delegate void DELEGATE();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
     private void simulateHeavyWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);

         ...lines of code to perform some search logs operation..
....
      }
 }
```

The functionality I want to achieve is that progress bar should report the progress of my function simulateHeavyWork() which is actually using UI thread as it needs to take input from my form controls and update it as well.

Now the problem which is happening is that code is actually calling simulateHeavyWork() and gives the output that is updating ui controls and work is done. (Note: I have used delegate here to avoid error cross controls running on ui thread as my function needs to use UI controls.)

Once that is done, it starts updating progress bar and which is wrong and looks like it calls simulateHeavyWork again and again with the gap of sleep(100).

Comment: Very strange approach. Background threads usually needed to prevent UI freezing on long-timed operations. So running background thread and immediately invoking from it delegate to run in UI thread (and freeze it) looks strange for me.

Comment: yep but I couldn't find any other easy way to do this, I want to show progress bar and allow user to cancel the operation as well. The problem is that long timed operation is actually using ui controls like a form button where user inputs data like id, date description etc and ask for the count of that number in the logs which needs to be again displayed on the form.

Comment: Well, maybe it will be better to split your logic - thus leave long-timed calculations in background, and update UI elements in `ProgressChanged` handler?

Comment: long time operations are actually using ui controls data and many other variables as input and it will again throw error of cross controls..

Comment: user3222101 You can use Dispatcher for UI thread and do time consuming jobs in BackgroundWorker without receiving any cross thread exception.

Comment: @user3222101 if your worker needs values from UI controls as input - you can pass these values as argument of `RunWorkerAsync`.

Comment: @Deniz- I am not that good in dotnet..if you can throw more light on this dispatcher for ui thread that will be more helpful..

Comment: @Andy- it looks good but I will need to make a lot of amendments in code which I don't want..:(

Comment: @user3222101 Code refactoring is usually good idea if it leads to more neat and efficient code, so don't be afraid of it. ;)

Comment: I tried the same and it got stuck on an error stating runworkerAsync does not take more than 10 arguments..!

Comment: Hmm... where do you find method override of `RunWorkerAsync` accepting more that one argument? Basically, it takes either none, or one single object. But this object can be instance of some your auxillary class and you can pass all information you need in this class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user3222101, as Andy stated before, you are running simulateHeavyWork() continuously. Moreover, by calling Invoke you are running this method in the UI thread which cause an extra sleep in the UI thread. Basically Invoke uses the message loop (pump) of the Control you use it on (Form1 in that case) and put your delegate to the queue of the UI thread in order to execute. This is not a good practice I think, due to the Sleep() call and time consuming log operations in your simulateHeavyWork() method.

I hope, understand you problem clearly.What I suggest is separation of the time consuming log operations from UI thread. Do not spend the valuable time of UI thread with slow and boring I/O operations. Get the values from the controls (using Invoke in the `BackgroundWorker` as I will explain below), do whatever you want in `BackgroundWorker` and update your GUI (again using Invoke) without touching the UI thread for this kind of heavy tasks.

As Andy suggested, you can pass data via the parameter of `RunWorkerAsync` and you should create a class which can store any data you need (because it accepts only one parameter). However, you can get the values from your Form whenever you need from another thread by using Invoke. [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
method also returns the value from your delegate (please see the example at the link below) and this gives you a chance to get the values of your controls on the form. Create a delegate which returns an object of type class that you crated for `RunWorkerAsync` and use this values in the `BackgroundWorker` thread. Please, have a look at the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092519/winforms-thread-safe-control-access).

```
public static string GetTextThreadSafe(this TextBox box)
{
    return GetTextBoxText(box);
}
```

Also, example uses [Func<...>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to return value.

By this way you can sleep (in `BackgroundWorker` thread) for a while then get the values from your controls (current values) and do whatever you want (again in `BackgroundWorker` thread). I think, this improves your code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question: *"which is wrong and looks like it calls simulateHeavyWork again and again with the gap of sleep(100)."*

Of course it calls. Just look at your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
   Delegate del= new DELEGATE(simulateHeavyWork);
    this.Invoke(del);
```

So you are calling `simulateHeavyWork` 100 times here. And since you've typed `Thread.Sleep(100);` in the body of `simulateHeavyWork` - gap between calls is about `Sleep(100)`

Comment: yeah..any way if you can suggest to achieve this would be great?

Comment: @user3222101 I think you should not use delegate running in UI thread, and do all your work in `_DoWork`. Then, somehow determine your current progress (the way of doing it depends on your concrete task. If it's some log search as it stated in your code - than maybe it is ratio of current log line number and total lines count), and based on change of that progress call [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method override accepting `object userState` where you can pass anything you need to `ProgressChanged` handler.